# (Argument list too long) While opening a large list of files using *cat*

Tags: bash, cat

I'm trying to do something like

```
cat */httprobe-subdomains.out | xargs -n1 -I{} -t sh -c 'curl -k -i --write-out "\n++++++++++\nResponse Code: %{response_code}\nRedirection URL: %{redirect_url}\nContent Size: %{size_download}" "http://{}" -L >> response/http-{}.out '
```

The response is

```
-bash: /usr/bin/cat: Argument list too long
```

If I tried to `cat */httprobe-subdomains.out` the stderr will be the same `-bash: /usr/bin/cat: Argument list too long`

I wish I had a way to escape this situation and be able to cat all httprobe-subdomains.out files in * folders and give it to xargs to deal with.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The *Argument list too long* error is documented in [errno(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) (as `E2BIG`) and related to some [execve(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) system call done by your [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) shell. Use [sysconf(3)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sysconf.3.html) with `ARG_MAX` to query that limit.

You have several approaches:

- recompile your Linux [kernel](https://kernel.org/) to raise that limit.
- write some small C program using appropriate [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) more appropriately, or write some [Python](https://python.org/) script, or some [GNU guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) script, ... doing the same
- increase some limits, but using [setrlimit(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) appropriately (perhaps using the shell `ulimit` builtin).

See also the documentation and the source code of [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/)

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: These suggestions are quite impractical compared to the solutions in the linked duplicate such as using `find`.  And I don't think that adjusting any of the rlimits will help at all.

Comment: The question has a simple solution. Recompiling the kernel, or writing C code, is an over-complicated solution, which would increase, but *not* remove, the upper limit.

Comment: Several years ago I did recompile my Linux kernel to raise these limits. In practice it helped a big lot

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer